# haskell movie database no parse

Tags: database, haskell, exception, movie, haskell-prelude

I have been wondering why I keep getting the error:

> *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse.

This happens after i go through my code and select option 2.

This is defining Film

```
type Title      = String
type Director   = String
type Year       = Int
type Rating     = (String, Int)

data Film = Film Title Director Year [(Rating)] 
        deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
```

This is an example of the text file.

```
[Film "Blade Runner" "Ridley Scott" 1982 [("Amy",5), ("Bill",8), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",7), ("Megan",4)],
 Film "The Fly" "David Cronenberg" 1986 [("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",6)]]
```

This is the option 2 function.

```
allFilms :: [Film] -> String
allFilms [] = []
allFilms ((Film title director year ratings):films) = "\n Title: " ++ title ++ "\n Director: " ++ director ++ "\n Year: " ++ show year ++ "\n Rating: " ++ printf "%3.2f" (averageRating ratings) ++ "\n" ++ allFilms films
```

This is the UI code  have so far:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
contents <- readFile "films.txt"
let database = (read contents :: [Film])
putStrLn "-----------------------------"
putStrLn "Welcome to the Movie Database"
putStrLn "-----------------------------"
putStrLn"Please Enter Your Name: "
user <- getLine
putStrLn user
menu database user

menu :: [Film] -> String -> IO()
menu database user = do
putStrLn "This is the Main Menu"
putStrLn "Choose one of the following options:"
putStrLn "2. give all films in the database"
putStrLn "Your Option:"
functionSelected <- getLine
if (read functionSelected :: Int) > 0 && (read functionSelected :: Int) < 9 then do
    putStrLn ("You chose option: " ++ functionSelected)
    completeFunction functionSelected database user
else do
    putStrLn "Incorrect option restarting menu."


completeFunction :: String -> [Film] -> String -> IO()
completeFunction "2" database user = do
putStrLn "Option 2: "
putStrLn (allFilms database)
```

I am aware the incorrect option restarting menu does not work yet.

Comment: The derived `Read` instance almost never do what you want it to do, you have to write a proper parser instead of `let database = (read contents :: [Film])`

Comment: I just cut and pasted your file identically, including the sample data, and it works for me.  There is nothing wrong with the `Read` instance.  I suspect that the data file you have is in the wrong format, perhaps?  Can you run `xxd films.txt` and show us what you have?

Comment: There's only one guarantee on `read`: you can `read` what has been `show`ed.

Comment: jamshidh was correct my full films.txt was incorrect thank you for the help